# Proof of Radon-Riesz Theorem for $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to know if there is a much more easy proof, in the particular case of $X=L^p, \, 1 <p <\infty$ of the following Radon-Riesz theorem:

> Let $X$ be uniformly convex, $(f_n)$ a sequence weakly convergent to $f \in X$ and suppose $\| f_n \| \to \|f\|$; then $f_n \to f$ strongly.

I will briefly recall the argument for this general case (I'm assuming you are acquainted with it, so I will recall only the main ideas. For the complete argument see, for instance, [here](https://matthewhr.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/uniform-convexity-and-reflexivity.pdf)). If $f = 0$, there is nothing to prove, so assume $f \neq 0$. Set $\phi_n := f_n / \| f_n \|$, $\phi = f / \|f\|$. The weak convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ implies that of $\phi_n$ to $\phi$. Using the uniform convexity, the Hahn-Banach theorem and the squeeze theorem, one shows that $( \phi_n )$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$; since $X$ is Banach, it converges in norm to $\phi' \in X$, so $f_n \to f' \in X$ in norm. Since norm convergence implies weak convergence, it follows $\phi_n \rightharpoonup \phi'$, which is equivalent to $f_n \rightharpoonup f'$. But the weak topology is Hausdorff, hence $f' = f$.

Obviously, this applies in particular to $L^p$ spaces (with $1 < p < \infty$). However, Exercise 1.8 of [AFP] asks to apply "*directly*" the uniform convexity property to prove  the Radon-Riesz theorem for $L^p$ spaces. This request seems suggest the existence of a more straightforward proof for this particular case. Is it so?

**Remark.** I'm not looking for the proof in [RN].

**Remark.** I was not concerned with the $L^1$ case at the beginning, since $L^1$ is not uniformly convex. However, if can prove/disprove the statement also for this case it would be of interest.

---

[AFP] Ambrosio, Fusco, Pallara, *Functions of bounded variation and free discontinuity problems*.
[RN] Riesz, Nagy, *Functional Analysis* p. 78-80.

Comment: by looking at your link, the uniform convexity is needed for proving that $\phi_n$ is Cauchy only from $\|\phi_n\| \le 2$, $\|\phi_n+\phi_m\| \to 2$. the other argument is by Hahn banach there is $f \in X^*$ with $\|f\|=1$ and $f(\phi)=1$, hence $\phi_n \to \phi$ weakly shows that $f(\phi_n+\phi_m) \to 2$, but since $f(\phi_n+\phi_m) \le \|phi_n+\phi_m\|$, we also have $\|\phi_n+\phi_m\| \to 2$.

Comment: In a uniformly convex space, a sequence $(x_n)$ that satisfies $\| x_n \| \leq 1$ for all $n$ and $\| (x_n + x_m) / 2 \| \to 1$ as $n, m \to \infty$ is Cauchy. This follows directly by uniform convexity. To show that it is indeed the case for $\phi_n$, one exploits Hahn-Banach and the uniform convexity, so get a left and right control on $\| (\phi_n + \phi_m) /2\|$, and these squeeze to 1 in the limit. I'm asking if $L^p$ spaces enjoy some peculiarity which simplify the proof, for example avoiding the use of Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Comment: Oh sure, $p=2$ is easy. The trouble is for $p \neq 2$

Comment: if $p=2$ yes clearly. and in the same way, in $L^p,l^p$ spaces there is the Holder inequality for making sense in practice to the Hahn-Banach theorem

Comment: my problem is more when $p=1$, with $L^1$ or $l^1$ NOT being uniformly convex, not even strictly convex. isn't the theorem still true ?

Comment: $p=1$ is not a case under consideration here. However, at leat for $\ell^1$, Schur property does the work

Comment: it is a case under consideration, since you are asking how the strict/uniform convexity is a key argument in the proof, right ?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there is some specific property of $L^p$ which makes the proof for the general case of uniformly convex space more direct. I don't want touch or weaken uniform convexity.

Comment: do you know this : [wiki/Hölder's_inequality#Extremal_equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hölder%27s_inequality#Extremal_equality) ?

Comment: Mmh, no. I haven't seen extremal equality before but they seem to be what I was looking for. Thank you.